# Cannot refresh a div with Ajax, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, html, refresh

I've placed a piechart inside a div, and would like to recalculate the data that feeds it, by pressing one of two links (count or total) on a webpage.

Here is my view excerpt :

```
<%= link_to "Count", {action: "switch_chart_dim"}, remote:true %>
<%= link_to "Total", retailers_switch_dim_path("total"), remote:true %>
<div id="visualization" > 
    <%= render partial: '/charts/highcharts_pie', locals: {pie_data: @pie_gender} %>
</div>
```

My controller :

```
def switch_chart_dim(type=:count)
    logger.debug("URRAY i am here")
    @pie_gender = Receipt.group_by_gender_pie(current_user, type,
                                              params["/retailers"][:begin_date], 
                                              params["/retailers"][:end_date])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :layout=>false }
    end
end
```

My js file (switch_chart_dim.js.erb)

```
$('#visualization').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial: '/charts/highcharts_pie', locals: {pie_data: @pie_gender})).html_safe %>')
```

I've read several posts on this, and tried to apply it all, but for some reason, it seems that my controller action isn't even being called (at least i cannot see my "URRAY" debug message on the logs).

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

Here is my matching route, if it might be relevant :

```
match '/retailers', to: 'retailers#switch_chart_dim', via: :post, as: "retailers_switch_dim"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found my problem with this one.

My routes file had two conflicting routes, and it was invoking the search action. I found this by analysing the request in Firebug:

```
match '/retailers', to: 'retailers#search', via: :post, as: "retailers_search"
match '/retailers', to: 'retailers#switch_chart_dim', via: :post, as: "retailers_switch_dim"
```

Solved it by replacing

```
match '/retailers', to: 'retailers#switch_chart_dim', via: :post, as: "retailers_switch_dim"
```

with

```
match '/retailers/switch_chart_dim', to: 'retailers#switch_chart_dim', via: :post, as: "retailers_switch_dim"
```